# R: plotting Google Earth Images with associated world files

Tags: r, matlab, geospatial, google-earth

Is there anyway to plot Google Earth images in R using a world file to geo-reference the image, like in Matlab?

Below is the Matlab function `worldfileread` from https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/worldfileread.html.

```
R = worldfileread(worldFileName,coordinateSystemType,rasterSize)
refmat = worldfileread(worldFileName)
```

Thanks in advance,
Nic

Comment: You could look into [ggmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/ggmap.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, that works. But still is not as simple as in Matlab as the `ggmap` package requires APIs and such.